# How to create restore point or bacpac file for Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool using Azure Powershell or GitHub Action

Tags: powershell, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have GitHub workflow that automatically export Azure SQL database (.bacpac) before a production deployment using Azure Powershell module. I was trying to achieve the same for Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool
However both `New-AzSqlDatabaseRestorePoint or New-AzSqlDatabaseExport` command is not working due to the fact that Server URL is different for Azure SQL database versus Azure Synapse analytics although microsoft documentation points to same instructions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-restore-points

the command did not support connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code to generate a restore point for synapse Dedicated pool:

```
$ResourceGroupName="$(Resource Group Name)"
$Server="$(Server)".split(".")
$ServerName=$Server[0]
$DatabaseName="$(Name)"
$Date=Get-Date 
$Label = $DatabaseName + "_Backup_" + $Date


New-AzSqlDatabaseRestorePoint -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -RestorePointLabel $Label
```

where $Server value is in format :
abc.database.windows.net